# at least one checkbox must stay selected on deselect action of one of them

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes on a form and i want to validate them when deselecting every one of them. So at least one checkbox must stay selected on deselect event.

```js
function validateCBox() {
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('myCBox');
var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            isChecked = true;
        };
    };
    if ( isChecked ) {
        alert( 'checked!' );
        } else {
            alert( 'please check at least one checkbox!' );
        }   
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "a">1
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "b">2 
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "c">3
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "d">4
</form>
<input type = "button" value = "Edit and Report" onClick="validateCBox()">
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you need register a `click` EventListener to call `validateCBox()` whenever a checkbox is clicked.

The reason for using a `click` EventListener is because you are able to cancel the event using `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('myCBox');

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        validateCBox(event);
    });
}

function validateCBox(event) {
    var isChecked = false;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (isChecked) {
        alert('checked!');
    } else {
        alert('please check at least one checkbox!');
        event.preventDefault();
    }   
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "a">1
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "b">2 
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "c">3
  <input type = "checkbox" class='myCBox' value = "d">4
</form>
<input type = "button" value = "Edit and Report" onClick="validateCBox()">
```

Comment: Thanks Tobby. Well, is it possible to select last one at the end of false proccess? I mean after warn

Comment: @radeveloper Updated answer, is that what you mean? Stop them from unchecking?

Comment: Yes. Thank you Toby.